# Rails devise simple form not saving all fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I went to generate the devise views I wanted to modify the new registration page to capture more than just the email & password. My devise user model has fields like `first name` `last name` `address` and many more.

This is my form as of right now

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {class:'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="row">
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h2>About yourself</h2>
        <%= f.input :first_name, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :last_name, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :phone, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :addressL1, label: 'Address Line 1', required: true %>
        <%= f.input :addressL2, label: 'Address Line 2' %>
        <%= f.input :city, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :postalCode, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :province, required: true, collection: provinces, prompt: '<-- select -->' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

    </div>
</div>
```

How come when I submit the form only email and password get saved?

Comment: Lets see the log to see what is going on. Have you whitelisted the attributes?

Comment: Can you show your devise model as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the **[Rails and Devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise)** example application from the RailsApps project. I've also written a **[Rails Devise Tutorial](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise/)** that explains in detail how to add attributes to a Devise sign-up form.

You need to tell Devise that the additional attributes are "permitted parameters." Otherwise, the "strong parameters" security measure introduced in Rails 4.0 will simply drop the unpermitted parameters, creating a new user without setting the additional attributes.

There are three different ways to add permitted parameters in Devise:

- override the default Devise registrations controller
- add code to the Application controller
- add an initializer file

The third way is the simplest. Add a file to your application:

```
# config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb

module DevisePermittedParameters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name << :last_name << :phone << :addressL1 << :addressL2 << :city << :postalCode << :province
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :first_name << :last_name << :phone << :addressL1 << :addressL2 << :city << :postalCode << :province
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

You can see that you pass the additional parameters to the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` method. These two lines tell Devise to accommodate additional attributes. If you want to add other attributes, or different attributes, modify these two statements.

The rest of the file implements a Rails *concern*. Concerns are modules that can be mixed into models and controllers to add shared code. Typically, these modules go in a *app/controllers/concerns/* folder and are added to a controller with an `include` keyword. In this case, we use the Ruby send method to add our mixin to the `DeviseController` object, adding `include DevisePermittedParameters` to the DeviseController without actually editing the code.

After making these changes and trying the application, you should see the additional attributes in the user record. If it doesn't work, show us more of your code, including the user model and controller.

Comment: +1 This seems better. I have never used it before but would definitely try it out.

Comment: I find the second way to be the simplest but I upvoted this

Answer (score 4):

In `Rails 4` with the introduction of *Strong Parameters*, parameter sanitization was moved from model to controller level. This needs to be taken care of when adding additional fields (other than `email` and `password`) to a *devise model*. Currently, you have not done this that is why only `email` and `password` fields are getting saved in the database and NOT the additional fields.

You can resolve this by permitting the additional attributes of devise model via a `before_action` in `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #... 
  ## Add this before_action
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    ## To permit attributes while registration i.e. sign up (app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :attrb1 << :attrb2 

    ## To permit attributes while editing a registration (app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :attrb1 << :attrb2
  end
end
```

where,

you need to replace `:attrb1`, `:attrb2` with the name of attributes that you want to permit. For example `:first_name`, `:last_name` and so on.

Refer to [Devise: Strong Parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters) for additional information.

Comment: Kirti, your answer is accurate, and it is described on the Devise README, but there is a drawback to the approach.  Every request to your web application must be evaluated to determine if it uses a Devise controller. It adds unnecessary overhead. See my answer for another approach.

Comment: Yup. I was just going through it and missed your comment. I like your approach better. :) Even I didn't like the unnecessary overhead suggested on Devise README but I never thought of this kinda approach. Thanks for educating Daniel.

Comment: Yes. Thats's true. BTW, yours was the first Ruby on Rails book that I read. I liked the step by step and end-to-end approach you took in the book and definitely learned a lot. Glad to be linkedin. :)