# Validates acceptance always fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

No other answers I found  on that issue helped me.

I have a terms and conditions box and want to validate if it's checked on creation.

In my model:

```
  validates :terms_and_conditions, :on => :create, acceptance: true, :allow_nil => false
```

In my view:

```
<%= f.check_box(:terms_and_conditions )%>
```

It always fails, no matter if the `check_box` is checked or not. I think it never actually sets the field and the problem is in my view, but I can't find it.

Log when submitting the form.

```
    Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xNNmGTWSV4hkj0rrlZeOq+AiTlJ9sc9+cAT1Sy0bjhc=", "user"=>{"email"=>"sdasdr@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "name"=>"", "surname"=>"", "country_id"=>"", "language"=>"", "description"=>"", "register_as_company"=>"1", "terms_and_conditions"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: name, surname, country_id, language, description, register_as_company, terms_and_conditions
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'sdasdr@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36mCountry Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "countries".* FROM "countries"[0m
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_auth_widget.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 127ms (Views: 22.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: What is the Rails version that you are using? Can you share the server log generated upon form submission with the `terms_and_conditions` field checked.

Comment: Is the `:terms_and_conditions` virtual attribute or db referenced? Have you tried to use `acceptance: {accept: true}` form ?

Comment: @dimuch, it's not db referenced, its virtual and I tried that form (same result).

Comment: @KirtiThorat, rails 4. I added the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not permitted `terms_and_conditions` attribute to be saved in the database. If you notice the server logs closely,

```
Unpermitted parameters: name, surname, country_id, language, description, register_as_company, terms_and_conditions
```

there are multiple attributes which are not permitted so all of them are not getting saved in database. `terms_and_conditions` goes as `nil` and results in error as the value submitted via form is ignored (because of unpermitted status).

This is related to Rails 4 Strong Parameters concept wherein only those attributes would be saved in database which are whitelisted/ permitted.

Checkout the information on [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Also, as per the server log I noticed that these attributes are part of `User` model which is a `Devise` model. Permitting attributes for Devise can be done in different ways, 
you can refer to [SO Question: Rails devise simple form not saving all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293370/rails-devise-simple-form-not-saving-all-fields) for this.